# Не открывается сайт фронтенд zabbix-web

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, docker-compose, zabbix

В докере развернут zabbix, все работало, после перезапуска перестал открываться веб-интерфайс zabbix (zabbix-web), расположен в контейнере, доступ к контейнеру идет через проксирующий сервер nginx-proxy.

Все контейнеры расположены в одной сети.

При подключении через браузер к контейнеру веб морды zabbix выдает 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable, ошибку выдает nginx-proxy (проксирующий сервер), так же у него в логах ошибка при подключении [error] 260#260: *8088 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client:...

Контейнеры видят друг друга, пинг проходит, но входе в сам контейнер nginx-proxy,  команда

```
curl http://172.18.0.4
```

выдает ошибку (где контейнер http://172.18.0.4  - контейнер zabbix-web)

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to 172.18.0.4:80; Connection refused
```

В самом контейнере zabbix-web ошибки отсутствуют.

Вывод команды docker ps:

```
    de55b2e096d0   zabbix_zabbix-web            "docker-entrypoint.sh"   13 hours ago   Up 13 hours   0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, :::8443->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp, :::8081->8080/tcp                                  zabbix-web

    19c58e8112a7   zabbix_zabbix-server         "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   13 hours ago   Up 13 hours   0.0.0.0:10051->10051/tcp, :::10051->10051/tcp                                                                         zabbix-server

    f77c14f28a7b   zabbix_mysql-server          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 hours ago   Up 13 hours   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                                                                  db_zabbix

    b37bb74a3d63   jwilder/whoami               "/app/http"              15 hours ago   Up 13 hours   8000/tcp                                                                                                              whoami

    3c9136c49972   jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine   "/app/docker-entrypo…"   15 hours ago   Up 13 hours   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   proxy
```

Подскажите, что может быть, в каком направлении копать?

Comment: что покажет команда docker ps ?

Comment: добавил вывод команды docker ps в тело вопроса

Comment: Недостаточно информации: запущен ли zabbix на хосте (процесс)? Если да, то что в логах самого zabbix-сервера - "доходит"ли до него запрос? Мне все же кажется, что процесс убит, а прокси не может тупо достучаться.

Comment: http://172.18.0.4 - у вас порт 80 или все же 8088? Уточните, так как в тексте противоречия.

Answer (score 0):

Из ошибки следует что настроен upstream на порту 80, а zabbix-web слушает на порту 8080.

Вам нужно проверить конфиг upstream в контейнере proxy.